# Show logo on magento session

Tags: magento

I have uploaded the different 2 logos for each customer, I need to show their own logo on magento catalog after login - is this possible? The logo have to fetch from media/avatar/dummy.jpg on customer login.

Currently i am in `header.phtml` file, any suggestion

```
<?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
    <h1 class="logo">
        <strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" />
        </a>
    </h1>
<?php else:?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a manageable number of custom logos - i.e. several, not hundreds - I'd suggest using customer groups. Assign each customer to their own group, then in your header code you can use `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();` to get the group ID of the current customer.

You can then modify your logo URL as you see fit based on the returned group ID.